# Cross thread operation not valid when trying to hide the form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows application which has 2 forms. Iam trying to achieve this:

When the second form is displayed, I want the first form to be hidden.

I have tried like:

```
public Executor()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Form1.ActiveForm.Hide();
}
```

But results in ***"cross-thread operation not valid control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"*** before getting started the entire application.

How can I achieve what I said? Also in my later code I am trying to close as shown above with the code `Form1.ActiveForm.Close();`

Any ideas would be really appreciated..

Comment: Have you tried to search your error message before posting this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a delegate to invoke the Close method on the subject form's thread:

```
    private delegate void BlankDelegate();

    private void CloseForm()
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new BlankDelegate(this.CloseForm));
        }
        else
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access UI controls (or their parent form) from a thread other than the one running that form's  UI thread

Try this-

```
 this.Invoke((Action)delegate { Form1.ActiveForm.Hide(); });
```